# How to avoid remaining white screen on webview android app

Tags: java, android, android-webview

**activity_main**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.google.httpwww.google.MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
    package com.google.httpwww.google;

import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView webview;

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webview.canGoBack()) {
            webview.goBack();
        } else {

            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

        WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/");
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.google.httpwww.google">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

As I run the app it gives white blank page with header as name of app. On internet most of case is based on at the begining of app there is white page but in my case it's remaining. Is there any idea what I am doing wrong?

P.S: I am new about android apps what I need just a app which will show my website.

Comment: in your MainActivity it's showing package name as "com.google.httpwww.google", but in your AndroidManifest it's showing  package="com.smotretmultik.httpwww.smotretmultik". Please check the package name. Try to set package name as com.google.httpwww.google in your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Also try `<RelativeLayout` instead of `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout` in your activity_main.xml

Comment: @Steven I add RelativeLayout withclosing tag but there is no improvement.

Comment: @Victor edit your post so I can see where you placed the `<RelativeLayout` tag